# Install Trac on 64bits Windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7, 64-bit, bug-tracking, trac

I'm configuring a new Developing Server that came with Windows 7 64bits.

It must have installed Trac with Subversion integration.

I install Subversion with VisualSVN 2.1.1, clients with TortoiseSVN 1.6.7 and AnkhSVN 2.1.7 for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 integration.

All works fine! my problem begun when going to Trac installation.

I install python 2.6 all fine.
Trac hasn't a x64 windows installer, so I installed it manually by compiling it with python console (C:\Python26\python.exe C:/TRAC/setup.py install).
After that, I can create TRAC projects normally, the Trac core is working fine. And so the problem begins, lets take a look at the Trac INSTALL file:

---

---

Requirements

To install Trac, the following software packages must be installed:

- Python, version >= 2.3.
- Subversion, version >= 1.0. (>= 1.1.xrecommended)
- Subversion SWIG Python bindings (not PySVN).
- PySQLite,version 1.x (for SQLite 2.x) or version 2.x (for SQLite 3.x)
- Clearsilver, version >= 0.9.3 (0.9.14 recommended)

---

Python:    OK

---

Subverion: OK

---

Subversion SWIG Python bindings (not PySVN): 
Here I face the first issue, he asks me for 'cd' to the swig directory and run the 'configure' file, and the result is:

```
C:\swigwin-1.3.40> c:\python26\python.exe configure

  File "configure", line 16
    DUALCASE=1; export DUALCASE # for MKS sh
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

PySQLite, version 1.x (for SQLite 2.x) or version 2.x (for SQLite 3.x):
Don't need, as Python 2.6 comes with SQLLite

---

Clearsilver, version >= 0.9.3 (0.9.14 recommended):
Second issue, Clearsilver only has 32bit installer wich does not recognize python installation (as registry keys are in different places from 32 to 64 bits).
So I try to manually install it with python console. It returns me a error of the same kind as SWIG:

```
C:\clearsilver-0.10.5>C:\python26\python.exe ./configure

  File "./configure", line 13
    if test -n "${ZSH_VERSION+set}" && (emulate sh) >/dev/null 2>&1; then
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

---

When I simulate a web server using the "TRACD" command, it runs fine when I disable svn support but when I try to open the web page it shows me a error regarding ClearSilver is not installed for generating the html content.

AND (for making me more happy) This TRAC will run over IIS7, I mustn't install Apache...

I'm nearly crazy with this issue... HELP!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect that [Trac on Windows](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracOnWindows) instructions should work on x64, even if they're 32-bit packages.  Have you tried this and failed?

---

Subversion SWIG Python bindings:

`configure` is not meant to be run by Python; it's meant to be run with a POSIX sh, like Bash or ksh.  However, if you read [subversion/bindings/swig/INSTALL](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/subversion/trunk/subversion/bindings/swig/INSTALL?view=markup) you'll find that the installation instructions for Windows *do not* use `configure`; instead, Visual Studio and `gen-make.py` are used.

Note that your bindings should match your installed Subversion.

---

Clearsilver:

Likewise, `configure` is meant for a sh, not Python.  Clearsilver compilation instructions for Windows can be found in [clearsilver/python/README.txt](http://code.google.com/p/clearsilver/source/browse/trunk/python/README.txt).

Comment: Woah!
I didn't know about this Trac on Windows page!
I was suffering so bad without it =[
I'll try it now!

Comment: As I've expected, you're totally right!
Trac is installed and working well.
I used the BitNami auto-installer, it rocks!

My first idea was to put it working over IIS7, BitNami auto-installs Apache... but its ok...

I'm only facing a problem on pointing the SVN repository, its not working at all...

The point is yours, but if you can help me with this issue, I'll be glad =]

Comment: @Tufo: I recommend you ask a new question with more details -- there's not much I (or anyone else) can deduce from a "it's not working" comment.

Answer (score 3):

Just export Register from [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python] to [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python].

It's happens because trac only see the [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python] and you installed the python "For all users"

Comment: Great solution this as I selected the "For all users" option and when I changed it to just the current user all was sorted. Thanks @Magno

Comment: Don't know, if this issue is fixed for 1.0, but 0.12 still needs this little patch.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I'm not the only one trying to install Trac on Win 7 64-bit, only to see the install crash and burn.

One problem is the lack of installed registry entries for Python on Win x64, which I was able to find via a web search. The problem was identified months ago, but unfortunately no patch release has been made available.

I was almost ready to give up on Trac, but the information here has given me new hope. Thanks all!